# Infragistics controls for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, wpf-controls, infragistics, netadvantage

I want to use Infragistics controls in my android application which i am creating in Eclipse IDE. But i cannot find a way to integrate these controls with eclipse. I have downloaded the file named NetAdvantage from

http://www.infragistics.com/products/android/

But I cannot find a way to use it in my project. When I try to install it, it installs it for Visual Studio. Can anybody please tell me some way as my application is in java not in C# or VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are referring to the IGUANA UI toolset? In this case I suggest choosing the **"Iguana UI 2012 Complete Bundle"** download option on the IG Website.

IGUANA UI actually does not require installation - the toolset as well as the documentation and product samples (including sample source code) are all available in the downloaded zip.

Please let me know if this helps.